# How to terminate simulation in SimPy 4

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

Is there a way to terminate the simpy simulation by using a command like env.exit()? I don't understand how to place an event into `env.run(until=event)`. I want to terminate the simulation when there are no objects left in my certain `Simpy Stores`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is an event in simpy, even the environment itself. Thus, you can terminate the simulation marking as succeed the "root" event.

```
# Save the event somewhere
end_event = env.event()

# Later, when you want to terminate the simulation, run
end_event.succeed()
```

In order to check if a store is empty, just check if its `items` len is equal to zero.

If you put all together, you can do something like that to solve your problem:

```
store = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity=10)
if len(store.items) == 0:
    end_event.succeed()
```

Comment: You are welcome @kerim, I am glad I have helped you

Answer (score 1):

So the whole example could be:

```py
env = simpy.Environment()
end_envt = env.event()

def process(store):
  yield store.get()
  if len(store.items) == 0:
    end_event.succeed()

store = simpy.FilterStore(env, capacity=10)
env.process(process(store))
env.run(until= end_envet)
```